# Page title always displaying "Error"

Tags: routes, 8

I am porting the [Disqus module to Drupal 8](https://github.com/andytruong/disqus).

The new routes are working fine, except for the page title, which always displays "Error" instead of the desired title. I have already implemented `hook_menu()`.

[image: screenshot]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong in the error handling with recoverable fatal errors.

They're not displayed but the affect the page title. Have a look at the watchdog output, there you should see some PHP errors.

This is a bug, so not really a good question for here, but for the time being, might help others.

Opened https://drupal.org/node/2100123

Answer (score 0):

Static titles for a route can be defined with `_title` under `defaults` in the module.routing.yml file:

```
disqus.admin:
  path: '/admin/config/services/disqus'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\disqus\Form\DisqusSettingsForm'
    _title: 'Some static title'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer disqus'
```

You can also use `_title_callback` if you need to define a dynamic title. Full details in [this change record](https://drupal.org/node/2095317).

Comment: I have just changed the route per your sugguestion: https://github.com/andytruong/disqus/blob/8.x-1.x/disqus.routing.yml, I also flushed the cache, the page title is still "Error". The screenshot: http://www.flickr.com/photos/99346699@N02/9973433434/